# How to make content navigation button (remains pressed when clicked) in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I created basic vertical layout that work as side menu and now I want to place some buttons in it. Few of them gonna work as common side menu buttons, they just change page content so I want to mark that they are clicked in some way, how can I achive that? Or maybe there is better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the 5th version of Vaadin7 manual, you can attach an event listener to the `Button`.

```
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // show the button has been clicked with a CSS class:
        button.addStyleName("v-button-clicked");
    }
});
```

Don’t forget to define the `v-button-clicked` class. Of course you’re free to add the class of your liking through the `.addStyleName()` method.

Comment: oh, I did not think about styles! shame on me, thanks!